# Java wrapper for the Stack Exchange API 2.0?

Tags: discussion, api-v2, java

I've checked out StackWrap4J, but it looks like it doesn't support some of the new methods provided in the v2.0 API (specifically the ones having to do with user authentication). Does anyone know if one already exists?

Just want to double-check before I begin parsing `JSON` responses myself.

---

I've pretty much confirmed that there are currently no Java wrappers around the StackExchange API v2.0. I've looked at the source code for StackWrap4J and thought about extending it myself and possibly contributing to the project because it would make life a LOT easier. However, it looks like v1.1 of the API will no longer be supported, so I'm wondering if using the StackWrap4J source code as a starting point is a good idea in the first place?

If someone with more knowledge about the APIs could explain the differences between v1.1 and v2.0, that'd be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, well, I've pretty much confirmed that A LOT has changed with version 2.0... the new release does not appear to be backwards compatible with version 1.1 at all. Kind of annoying if you ask me. For now I'm going to modify StackWrap4J myself and just copy and paste the modified source code into my app... if anyone is interested in partnering up to extend the library for version 2.0, let me know!

Comment: Hey, I'd be interested in getting StackWrap4J up to 2.0 standards. Would you be able to contribute your changes to the Source Forge project?

Comment: From what I know about the changes, it will probably be best to only use some of the HTTP stuff from StackWrap4J and probably start over on the rest.

Comment: @jjnguy In all honesty, I didn't really end up modifying/extending all that much (I was mostly concerned with badges, inbox items, notifications, etc.). I do feel like I have a pretty good understanding of how StackWrap4J works though (I looked through probably 80% of the source code), so I'd be able to contribute I think. I would hate for v3.0 to come out though and potentially ruin any work we put into v2.0... what would be the best way to write the library given that it will eventually need to be brought up to 3.0 standards?

Comment: How soon is 3.0 supposed to be released?

Comment: @jjnguy Not 100% sure (and last time I checked they hadn't even ball-parked it). API 2.0 has out of beta for about 6 months now so I'd guess sooner rather than later (?). From what I can tell 3.0 is going to be mostly an extension of 2.0 (i.e. the addition of write-only API calls). That said, there are some parts of the documentation that say things like "this could be changed at any time" etc. and I'm not always certain which parts should be trusted.

Comment: I think it's safe to develop against the 2.0 release. Otherwise you end up waiting for a release that isn't even scheduled yet.

Comment: @jjnguy I can help out if you need me... you're one of the people who actually wrote StackWrap4J, correct?

Comment: I am! I'll see what I can throw together over the weekend.

Comment: If something comes of this I'll be happy to participate.  I've been researching creating a Holo-based Stack Exchange Android app and a Java wrapper is just what I need.  Still green on my Java but I'll have a look at the StackWrap4J code and will lend my help in any way I can.

Comment: have we had any news?

Comment: Hi - any update on bringing the StackWrap4J project up to date and using the 2.0 (now 2.1) version of the API? Would it make sense to perhaps move the project itself onto github so that contributions are easier to do (via pull requests)?