# Java Wrapper for the 2.2 API

Tags: support, api-v2.2, java

I've been looking for a Java based API/wrapper/DAO for the new SE API 2.2. but could not find any (May very well be a limitation of my search skills, though.)

I found references to attempts at previous version, but they seem to be either very limited in scope or no longer compatible with the latest version.

- [Java wrapper for Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/231/java-wrapper-for-stack-exchange) from 6 years ago
- [Java wrapper for the Stack Exchange API 2.0?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3572/java-wrapper-for-the-stack-exchange-api-2-0?rq=1) from 4 years ago
- [StackExchange API Java SDK](https://stackapps.com/questions/4716/stackexchange-api-java-sdk) and [StackExchange API Java wrapper](https://stackapps.com/questions/4604/stackexchange-api-java-wrapper) from 2 years ago

Q: is there a more or less comprehensive Java library to query api.stackexchange.com programmatically? (Or do I need to write one...?)

Comment: That last library claims to support  API V2.2.  You can also fork it at GitHub if needed.  Other than that, [Java support is still sparse](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/java+library).

Comment: I know. However when I looked at the actual github repo it was... how do I put it... there was still plenty of room for improvement.

Comment: This question comes up, every couple of years, and the answer is still the same:  Nothing out there that is quite ready for Prime Time...   Demand is low... Maybe you could be the hero that writes a good, current library. ;)